# Dont know php need some information if this is right. It is a contact page

Tags: php, html

this is the html

its called contact.html the php is external file.

this  the php

```
 <form action="mailer.php"  method="post">

          <label>Name</label>
        <input name="name" placeholder="Type Here">

        <label>Email</label>
        <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Type Here">

        <label>Contact Number</label>
        <input name="number" type="text" placeholder="Type Here">

        <label>Message</label>
        <textarea name="message" placeholder="Type Here"></textarea>
        <br/>

        <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">

    </form>
```

below is the php the file is  called mailer.php. I need to know if this form will work and if 
not what could be wrong. Or if you have alternative suggestions. 
Thanks for help.

```
 <?php
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $number = $_POST['number'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        $from = 'From:me'; 
        $to = 'me@hotmail.com'; 
        $subject = 'Hello';

        $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Number: $number\n Message:\n $message";




 if ($_POST['submit']) {
        if ($name != '' && $email != '') {
            if ($human == '4') {                 
                if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
                echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
            } else { 
                echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
            } 
        } else if ($_POST['submit'] && $human != '4') {
            echo '<p>You answered the anti-spam question incorrectly!</p>';
        }
        } else {
            echo '<p>You need to fill in all required fields!!</p>';
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Why don't you try and see what happens

Comment: Your mailer.php file is checking to see if `$human` is equal to 4, however you don't seem to capture, pass, or set that variable anywhere.

Comment: i cant see, i know nothing about php. help

Comment: just upload everything and load your form, fill and submit, see what happens. you get any error message or you get the mail

Comment: Then give us more context - can't you run this? If you can't, then what is the purpose of doing this? Writing php you can't run / test is futile - there's all sorts of potential issues (does the `mail` function work? Is your php configured properly? etc)

Comment: If you know nothing about PHP, learn some before!

Comment: very well. [helping](http://www.php.net). (not .com, argh...)

Comment: @MasterAM I think you meant http://php.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing i see wrong is `$human` any reference to. You have not declared this anywhere. I would assume this is a capture of some kind. Maybe an input field with a label reading "whats 2+2". If 4 is written inside the input field then it is human, if not then it is a bot. This is low level bot testing but may be sufficient for your needs. A hidden field that should remain empty is also a good way to test for bots. A bot would screen read and fill in a hidden field thus making the form invalid.

```
<form action="mailer.php"  method="post">

          <label>Name</label>
        <input name="name" placeholder="Type Here">

        <label>Email</label>
        <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Type Here">

        <label>Contact Number</label>
        <input name="number" type="text" placeholder="Type Here">

        <label>Message</label>
        <textarea name="message" placeholder="Type Here"></textarea>
        <br/>

        <label>What's 2+2</label>
         <input name="human" type="number" placeholder="Type Here">
        <br/>

        <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">

    </form>
```

php

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$number = $_POST['number'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$from = 'From:me'; 
$to = 'me@hotmail.com'; 
$subject = 'Hello';
$human = $_POST['human'];

// rest of code
```

at the end of your php file put this and it will take them to a thank you page that you can create

```
header("Location: thanks.html");
```

or you could put this

```
header("Location: contact.php?thanks");
```

Note that you will need to change the file extension on your contact page from `.html` to `.php`. This is so then we run `php` on your page and check to see if the page is being loaded from the php file and if it is we can display a thank you message instead of the form.

Change your form to look like this. It will check to see if the page has been loaded from the php file.

```
<?php
if($_REQUEST["thanks"]) {
    ?>
    <p>Thanks for your form submition</p>
    <?php
} else {
?>
  <form action="mailer.php"  method="post">

          <label>Name</label>
        <input name="name" placeholder="Type Here">

        <label>Email</label>
        <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Type Here">

        <label>Contact Number</label>
        <input name="number" type="text" placeholder="Type Here">

        <label>Message</label>
        <textarea name="message" placeholder="Type Here"></textarea>
        <br/>

        <label>What's 2+2</label>
         <input name="human" type="number" placeholder="Type Here">
        <br/>

        <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">

    </form>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: $human = $_POST['human'];              this should work now?

Comment: thanks alot. How do i make the form clear when the user has added their data? to say sent or something.

Comment: I've edited my answer to show you how to display thank you

Answer (score 0):

At the very least, your mailer.php file is going to fail because $human is not being set, but is being checked / required for the email to send.

Below I have added a line (with a comment above) which will allow the mail to send.

**Warning:** Making this change will open this form up for bots to use / spam with!

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$number = $_POST['number'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$from = 'From:me'; 
$to = 'me@hotmail.com'; 
$subject = 'Hello';
// To at least get it to run, add the below (this will allow spamming, but get the form to work)
$human = 4;

$body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Number: $number\n Message:\n $message";




if ($_POST['submit']) {  
    if ($name != '' && $email != '') {
        // $human variable is not being set above, so this will never pass
        if ($human == '4') {                 
            if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
                echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
            } else { 
                echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
            } 
        } else if ($_POST['submit'] && $human != '4') {
            echo '<p>You answered the anti-spam question incorrectly!</p>';
        }
    } else {
        echo '<p>You need to fill in all required fields!!</p>';
    }
}
?>
```